# Building Dictionary from elements of multiple smaller Dictionaries indexed by same key

Tags: c#, performance, linq, dictionary

I have one master `Dictionary<int, SolarSystem>` and several smaller `Dictionary<int, JumpsHelperClass>`, `Dictionary<int, KillsHelperClass>`, etc.  My `SolarSystem` class is made up of these smaller helper classes `JumpsHelperClass`, `KillsHelperClass`, etc.  They are all indexed by the same `int` key.

The problem is, these smaller Dictionaries are being populated by asynchronous api calls and my master class that holds the master `Dictionary<int, SolarSystem>` subscribes to be notified when they get new information to update its master list.  However, there is no guarantee that the master list has all the keys that the smaller list does when it is to be updated.  In fact, the master Dictionary could be entirely empty.

I have tried an approach like this:

```
    void JumpsRequest_UpdatedResults(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (int item in JumpsRequest.JumpsBySolarSystemID.Keys)
        {
            try
            {
                SolarSystemsByID[item].Jumps = JumpsRequest.JumpsBySolarSystemID[item];
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
            {
                SolarSystemsByID.Add(item, new SolarSystem(JumpsRequest.JumpsBySolarSystemID[item], new HelperClasses.KillsHelperClass()));
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is painfully inefficient.  This would fire every time the `JumpsRequest` gets new info from the api and updates its `Dictionary<int, JumpsHelperClass>`.  Is there a way I can merge the dictionaries in a way, avoiding the overhead of the try catch for every addition to the master.

The master Dictionary tends to hold about 4-8k elements at any given time for reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the main thing you are worried about is the try/catch you could use ContainsKey to check if the given key exists before attempting the update, e.g.:

```
   void JumpsRequest_UpdatedResults(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (int item in JumpsRequest.JumpsBySolarSystemID.Keys)
        {
            if (SolarSystemsByID.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                SolarSystemsByID[item].Jumps = JumpsRequest.JumpsBySolarSystemID[item];
            }
            else
            {
                SolarSystemsByID.Add(item, new SolarSystem(JumpsRequest.JumpsBySolarSystemID[item], new HelperClasses.KillsHelperClass()));
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to avoid doing two lookups in the dictionary (which the above code will do) you could also do something like:

```
   void JumpsRequest_UpdatedResults(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (int item in JumpsRequest.JumpsBySolarSystemID.Keys)
        {
            SolarSystem system;
            if (SolarSystemsByID.TryGetValue(item, out system))
            {
                system.Jumps = JumpsRequest.JumpsBySolarSystemID[item];
            }
            else
            {
                SolarSystemsByID.Add(item, new SolarSystem(JumpsRequest.JumpsBySolarSystemID[item], new HelperClasses.KillsHelperClass()));
            }
        }
    }
```